# In this case, do I need to perform MANOVA? If so, how should I proceed?

Tags: anova, manova

I tried to understand what kind of statistical analysis I have to do in my case but failed to grasp idea.

Let me first explain my experiment. I performed experiments to analyze the brain network difference among **three groups**; i.e. control, patient group1 and patient group2.
I have EEG signal with **five** different frequency bands in **21 areas**. I measured **three kinds** of network characteristic in every area (it yields a constant value). For example, 
if area number one is a central hub of the network it will have a high value in hub measure A.

***If I want to analyze which area has significant difference in which kind of network characteristic within which band frequency, what kind of statistical analysis should be done?***

If there is a single kind of measure with a frequency band and a brain area, it would be easy to understand that I have to perform ANOVA to see the group difference. I guess I need to perform MANOVA for my case but even not sure about this. I tried to understand by searching other examples but it was confusing as they were not exactly fit with my situation. 
Could you give me some clues to start with? 
(FYI, I know R and MATLAB. If you can give me some examples with R or MATLAB, I can understand.)
Thank you in advance. 
Sincerely, 
Jaejun